# Jenkins active choice parameter not understand the "@" symbol"

Tags: jenkins

**When I am using the Jenkins active choice parameter for email value, the Jenkins does not recognize the "@" symbol in the email**

[image]

**After saving this data on build with parameter section displays like this**

[image]

**How can I pass the email value as a parameter?**

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've been able to determine, the only *direct* solution is not to sandbox the script. This obviously causes other issues, especially for the poor sap who has to write the scripts.

As a workaround, I replace the problem characters (which include `+` and `=` as well as `@`) in the values, and then reverse the replacements where they're used (in my case this was another active choice, but it could just as easily be the pipeline itself).